# Подключение к серверу с домашнего компьютера, у которого нет доступа к серверу, через рабочий компьютер, у которого есть доступ к серверу

Tags: сеть

Есть comp1 это домашний компьютер, находится дома. Есть comp2 это рабочий компьютер. Есть comp3 это сервер к которому надо подключиться с comp1. comp1 и comp3 не соединены, comp1 не может напрямую по адресу обратиться к comp3. comp2 и comp3 соединены(вроде через туннель какой-то). comp1 и comp2 соединены через radmin vpn. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы написав в браузере на comp1 адрес comp3, получить ответ от этого сервера? Условно адрес comp3 10.10.10.10, а адреса comp1 и comp2 в radmin vpn 26.10.6.1 и 26.13.23.2.

Пробовал прописать статические маршруты на comp2, не уверен что правильно, не получилось.